# operator overloading<< error

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Im trying to overload the operator<<

```
const ostream & operator<<(const ostream& out, const animal& rhs){
    out << rhs.a;
    return out;
}
```

it seems that im getting an error because im return a const and also because the first argument is const refrence to an ostream object.

```
cout << objectOfAnimal1 << objectOfAnimal2 ;
```

it work just fine if I change the the return type and the operator signature to this one:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& out, const animal& rhs)
```

Comment: You are trying to write data into the ostream, that's not a very `const` operation!

Comment: @FatalError can you tell where Im modidying the object

Comment: const means the object won't be modified; when you write cout << objectofanimal1 you are writing to the ostream that you marked as const. the compiler is smart enough to know that it can't be const

Comment: A specific question would have helped this post. We can all infer the question, but I suspect we will all infer slightly different questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& out, const animal& rhs)
```

In your code You are trying to modify a `const` `ostream` object, and so you get the errors.
It should not be `const`.

Comment: yes I know that will work, but why when I change it const it wont work. thanks

Comment: @AlexDan: The point is, it cannot be `const`! because you are modifying the object state.

Comment: Im not changing anything about the ostream object

Comment: @AlexDan: Yes you are. You are streaming `rhs.a` into it (in the expression `out << rhs.a`).

Comment: @AlexDan: you're feeding stream with data; when you eat a lot of donuts, you're getting fat, hence going through changes. No const, no const at all.

Comment: thanks. what I was missing is that feeding stream with data will change it. so that's why I was getting an error

Comment: @tomasz : can you tell me when I feed data to a stream. what exactly  will change in the object stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& out, const animal& rhs){
out << rhs.a;
return out;
}
```

You've already explained what is probable reason of problem and you really didn't try it out?